# Conditionally add one CSS value

Tags: css, reactjs

In Home.js I have the following code

```
<div id="sub-container">
...
</div>
```

and in home.css I have the following code

```
#sub-container {
    ... // A lot of css
}
```

I want to conditionally add one value to the css. The only solution I found is to create a new block and add the line there

```
{condition ? (<div id="sub-container">) : (<div id="sub-container-2">)

#sub-container-2 {
    ... // A lot of css
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Is there another solution to optimize the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use an extra class ?

```
.sub-container-extra { justify-content: flex-end; }
```

And in component

```
<div id="sub-container" className={condition && 'sub-container-extra'}></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```
<div id={condition ? 'sub-container' : 'sub-container-2'}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your `sub-container-2` element:

```
<div id="sub-container-2" class="justify-flex-end">
```

Add set the styles as follows:

```
#sub-container, #sub-container-2 {
    /* ... A lot of css */
}

#sub-container-2.justify-flex-end {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

This works by applying all your global styles to both tags, and the extra style to only the tag with the specified class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of duplicating class, You can customize the main one

```
#sub-container {
    ... // A lot of css
    ... // A lot of css
    ... // A lot of css
}

#sub-container.special {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

And then just add the class to the div conditionally:

```
<div id="sub-container" {condition ? 'class="special"' : ''}></div>
```